# Additional element being mapped to hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm mapping two different arrays to a hash and for some reason it seems to be adding an additional element to the hash.  I have 5 elements in array @pids and array @time, I'm mapping them to hash %match and it's giving me a 6th element.  Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
print Dumper \@pids;
print Dumper \@time;
my %match = map { $_ => @time } @pids;
print Dumper \%match;
```

@pids:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '4690',
          '4692',
          '4693',
          '4696',
          '5320'
        ];
```

@time:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '23:59',
          '23:59',
          '23:59',
          '23:59',
          '23:59'
        ];
```

%match:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '4696' => '23:59',
          '4693' => '23:59',
          '4690' => '23:59',
          '4692' => '23:59',
          '23:59' => '23:59',
          '5320' => '23:59'
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each element of `@pids` you're assigning the whole array `@time`, the right syntax is:

```
my %match = map { $pids[$_] => $time[$_] } (0..@pids);
```

But, you'd better use this:

```
my %match;
@match{@pids} = @time;
```

Comment: that worked, thanks.  Why would that work and mapping it not work?

Comment: @cycloxr: It' because you're assigning the whole array `@time` to each element of `@pids`.

Answer (score 2):

'$_ => @time', here is the problem.
It works just like this:

```
   foreach my $key (@pids)
   {
        $map{$key} = $time[0];
        $map{$time[1]} = $time[2];
        $map{$time[3]} = $time[4];
   }
```